# comparing values sent to/from server by NetworkStream

Tags: c#, sockets, encoding, network-programming, tcpclient

When u know why the sent string "kamote" to server and the string received "kamote" from server are not the same..

**CLIENT**

```
    tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient.Connect(ServerIP, Port);
    connectionState = (HandShake("kamote", tcpClient)) ? "Connected to " + ServerIP.ToString() : "Host unreachable.";

    private bool HandShake(String str, TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        using (NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] toServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            ns.Write(toServer,0,toServer.Length);                
            ns.Flush();

            byte[] fromServer = new byte[10025];
            ns.Read(fromServer, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fromServer).Equals(str);
        }
    }
```

**SERVER**

```
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

    NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();

    byte[] fromClient = new byte[10025];
    ns.Read(fromClient, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

    byte[] toClient = fromClient;
    ns.Write(toClient, 0, toClient.Length);            
    ns.Flush();
```

Client sent "kamote"
Server received "kamote"
Server sent "kamote"
Client received "kamote"

`HandShake()` always returns false. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the previous question you asked, you're not keeping track of the number of bytes you received. So what's happening is this:

- On the client, you send the string "kamote".
- On the server, it receives that string into a buffer that's 10025 bytes long.
- The server then sends the entire buffer back to the client -- all 10025 bytes
- The client receives all or part of those 10025 bytes and converts them to a string.

The string that gets converted is really "kamote" with a bunch of 0's after it.

You *must* use the return value from `Read` to know how many bytes you received.

Comment: there.. i got it.. i use this return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fromServer).Substring(0,str.Length).Equals(str); to terminate the extra.. anyway, how to know if what is the length of bytes for this  string "kamote" ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try limiting the string length to the actual read bytes like this:

```
noOfBytes = ns.Read(bytes, 0, ...);
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, noOfBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are including a lot of 0 characters, since you are including the entire `fromServer` in getstring. 0s don't print, but they are there. You must tell it the correct number of bytes to decode.