# is 10025 a special value for allocating byte[]

Tags: tcp

I see several times in some code [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-client.htm) for TCP communication the following line:

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
```

Therefore I was wondering if this 10025 value has a special reason or if it is just arbitrary chosen.

Thanks

Comment: Looks arbitrary to me... but perhaps it's meaningful in the context. Where did this "some code" come from?

Comment: Interesting, I googled around and there's a SO question with the same buffer size : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218218/comparing-values-sent-to-from-server-by-networkstream

Comment: Probably the developer lives in New York, as 10025 is the ZIP code of New York :-)

Comment: @Sean There are more of those. How many of them do you think started by copying someone else's project? :)

Comment: @Sean That's some awful networking code :D That's probably code copied over and over without understanding what it actually does.

Comment: Change it by       client.ReceiveBufferSize = new_size

Comment: I can't find where i took the code from but as soon as i find it I will post it here.

Comment: here it is: http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-client.htm

Comment: @taktak004 Yeah, I would ignore that tutorial. It's just wrong on so many levels. For example, there's no guarantee you'll get the whole message with one Read, and just as importantly, there's no guarantee you wouldn't get two or more messages with the same Read. That's why you want to create your own protocol on top of TCP - at the very least, you should send the length of the data (in the case of the chat application, this could perhaps be saving an integer with the length of the string before the string itself; you'd then expect all data to start with this integer).

Comment: @Luaan  "there's no guarantee you wouldn't get two or more messages with the same Read."
What tell you that ?

And do you have a better tutorial in mind ?

Comment: @taktak004 Okay, I wanted to post a good tutorial on networking to get you started, but I couldn't actually find any. The internet seems to be full of extremely bad examples of networking. Seems like I've found a good topic to write an article about, after all those years :D A sample of the 2+ messages at once issue - if you send two messages one after another (under the 200ms timeout), the other side has no way to know that those are two separate messages - it will read both as one string. Note that this will not show up when testing on `localhost` on Windows :)

Comment: @taktak004 So unless you want to buy a book on the topic (and pick carefully), you might be out of luck. Studying other people's code will also help, but as you've seen, there's a lot of bad network code out there. What are you actually trying to do? There's a lot of things you have to consider when writing a network client / server. Alternate HTTP client? TcpClient is fine. A game? UDP might be more appropriate. Load-balancing socket server? Peer-to-peer chat? Scalable chat server? All those are very different :)

Comment: I have to write a simple chat server and client for an "interview". And I do not have so much time, few hours left :-). And one of the requirement is: "No message should be lost under any load"

Comment: @taktak004 It's great that you've even noticed that value as something you should understand. Definitely better than being asked on the interview and responding with a glassy look :))

Comment: @Luaan Are really planning to write a tutorial about networking ? If yes when do you think you will work on it ? I am impatient to read it :)

Comment: @taktak004 I'm not really sure if I can find some time for that, so I can't really say :) Although I suppose that doing the simple chat tutorial everyone does "done right" shouldn't be too much time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, 10025 doesn't have any specific meaning. It's probably a result of random tweaking by someone who doesn't understand how to use buffers (hey, I received a 10000 B packet, I didn't expect that, let me increase the buffer size...).

Less arbitrary values would be:

- Powers of two are often used, because they're quite handy in computing (which is based on binary numbers). So you'll often see buffer sizes like `256` or `4096`.
- `65536` - Apart from being a power of two, it's also the maximum size of a TCP payload without window scaling (which can increase the possible payload size to a crazy value of 1 GiB - that's one big packet).
- Actual known maximum size of the payload. This can be useful if the payload size is significantly smaller than the usual buffer sizes. For example, if you know that the largest payload you can receive is 100 B, you could use a byte array of 100 B, and you can even reuse it without issues (provided you don't *reference* the buffer anywhere, but you shouldn't really be doing that anyway).
- `1460` - This is usually the default TCP send buffer size (if you send anything less than this, TCP will wait for some time (say 200ms) before sending the "incomplete" buffer; this allows TCP to work relatively well if you're writing eg. individual bytes to the network stream without buffering them first). So sending a 4 kiB packet would mean that the first 2920 B would be sent immediately, while the remaining 1176 B would wait for the say 200ms "timeout". Not taking this into account can cause significant delays even though the network is actually not busy at all.

There's also some extra possible reasons in more specific environments. For example, on .NET, you may want to force the byte array to end up on the large object heap. While not entirely reliable, it should probably store objects larger than 85,000 B on the LOH (it would be nice if this could be enforced in some way). This can be handy if you really know what you're doing, especially if you need to keep pinned handles on the array (or its part), which is often the case in eg. asynchronous networking - pinned handles can cause significant issues on the main managed heap, because it relies on compaction to work (it always allocates on the end, while LOH has a table of free spaces).

On an even lower level, you might want to for example restrict the array size to fit well into CPU cache, or a single memory page to improve performance (this is also significant with .NET arrays, which store the array size at the beginning of the array - this means that when accessing the array's items, bounds checking will need to load the start of the array, instead of just the requested item). However, by the time you start with optimizations like this, you're probably a bit of a specialist :)

In other words, well chosen buffer size can be simply a good practice leading to less issues. In the end, though, it's all about profiling - if you find a performance problem in your networking code, a badly chosen buffer size is one of the possible culprits.

Also: WOW. So many google results on the `new byte[10025]` snippet. I wonder where that value originated, because it's obvious that a *lot* of people just blindly copied it without understanding it at all, best evidenced by snippets like this:

```
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
bufferSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, bufferSize);
```

Why the hell would you allocate a 10 025 byte buffer and then only ever read `ReceiveBufferSize` bytes into it? Not to mention that if `ReceiveBufferSize` (which has *nothing* to do with the data being sent) is bigger than 10 025 B, you're possibly going to get an out of bounds error. If you care about `ReceiveBufferSize` at all (and you probably shouldn't), why not create a `new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize]` buffer in the first place?

Comment: @taktak004 I see similar tidbits all over the google results. I'm stunned :D